# OCaml toplevel print current directory?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-toplevel

Within OCaml toplevel I am trying to print the current directory.

i.e.

```
# Filename.current_dir_name;;
```

which returns

```
- : string = "."
```

which is not very useful.

What is the toplevel command needed to display the full path of the current directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many system calls can be done via **sys**

In your case, 
**Sys.getcwd();;**